# Connecting two datasources to the same database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, multi-tenant

I am working on an application where we have decided to go for a multi-tenant architecture using [the solution provided by Spring](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/), so we route the data to each datasource depending on the value of a parameter. Let's say this parameter is a number from 1 to 10, depending on our clients id.

However, this requires altering the application-context each time we add a new datasource, so to start we have thought on the following solution:

- Start with 10 datasources (or more) pointing to different IPs and the same schema, but in the end all routed to the same physical database. No matter the datasource we use, the data will be sent to the same schema in this first scenario.
- The data would be in the same schema, so the same table would be shared among datasources, but each row would only be visible to each datasource (using a fixed where clause in every CRUD operation)
- When we have performance problems, we will create another database, migrate some clients to the new schema, and reroute the IP of one of the datasources to the new database, so this new database gets part of the load of the old one

Are there any drawbacks with this approach? I am concerned about:

- ACID properties lost
- Problems with hibernate sessionFactory and second level cache
- Table locking issues

We are using Spring 3.1, Hibernate 4.1 and MySQL 5.5

Comment: I would suggest that you give each tenant the option of choosing to have a separate database so you do not have the burden of monitoring the database and then migrating to new database if there are performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your spring-link is a little outdated, hibernate 4 can handle multi-tenancy pretty well on it's own. i would suggest to use the multiple schemas approach because setting up and initializing a new schema is programmatically relativly easy to do (for example on registration-time), if you have so much load though (and your database-vendor does not provide a solution to make this transparent to your application) you need the multiple database approach, you should try to incorporate the tenant-id in the database-url or something in that case http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html